# R - 2 covariate explanatory variables and a third categorical variable I need to colour code the data with

Tags: r, scatter-plot

In R, I am using the command `plot(Strength, Weight, col= Area)` to plot a scatterplot, with Weight as the explanatory numerical variable, and Area as the categorical explanatory variable, and Strength as the response.

There are, say, 6 areas, 1-6, but how can I tell which colour is associated with which area?

The scatterplot is coming out fine, but I can't tell which area the 6 colours on the scatterplot belong to.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a legend to your plot, see for instance https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/add-legend-to-plot-in-r/

But it will be easier to use the package `ggplot2`, which makes a legend for you, automatically. Something like, assuming your variables are in data frame `yourdata`  :

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(yourdata, aes(Strength, Weight, color= Area)) + 
geom_point()
```

Learning `ggplot2` (gg is "grammar of graphics") will save you time in the long run!